# Rails Polymorphic Redirect Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

Bumping into a redirect problem with nested resources and polymorphic associations. I think I can find a way forward however I'd like to find out what can be considered as best practice.

I have the following nested resources:

```
  namespace :navigate do
    resources :boks, :only => [:show] do
      resources :groups,  :only => [:show]
      resources :categories, :only => [:show]
      resources :tools, :only => [:show, :index]
      resources :artifact_types, :only => [:show]
      resources :artifacts, :only => [:show, :index]
      resources :processus do
        resources :notes, module: :processus
      end
    end
  end
```

Notes being a polymorphic association (that I will also later use with the Tool model).

Most of my code is inspired but the excellent gorails.com episode: https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations

The controller that I use to manage notes is:

```
class Navigate::NotesController < Navigate::NavigateController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @note = @noteable.notes.new note_params
    @note.user = current_user
    @note.save
    redirect_to [:navigate, @bok, @noteable], notice: "Your note was succesfully created."
  end

  def update
    @note = @noteable.notes.where(user: current_user).first
    if @note.update(note_params)
      redirect_to polymorphic_url([:navigate,*** HOW TO REFERENCE BOK ***, @noteable]), notice: "Your note has been updated."

    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Unable to update your note."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def note_params
      params.require(:note).permit(:content, :public)
    end
end
```

Note the  *** HOW TO REFERENCE BOK *** part. This is where my problem is. Once I update the "Note" I want to redirect to @noteable related controller (here Processus) but in order to construct the URL I need to have an @bok object which I don't have in this instance because I actually don't need it.

I can also retrieve the correct @bok model but I wonder if there is another way to deal with this redirect?

My URL for redirection should be http://localhost:3000/navigate/boks/1/processus/2 but in order to construct it I would need a Bok object which I haven't go in my controller above (as I don't need it).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a route for a nested object without the id of the object it is nested into.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it but I am getting another error:  undefined method `note_url' for #<Navigate::Processus::NotesController:0x007fcdd79c8a90>

Comment: Did you try using polymorphic_path instead of polymorphic_url? It sets the routing_type to path automatically

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the same type of error:       redirect_to polymorphic_path(@note), notice: "Your note has been updated." --> undefined method `note_path' 

In fact, there is not direct path to Note because it only leaves within a bok\processus\ context.

Comment: I finally understood, since the resource is mapped under bok, you'd need a bok object since note is nested within it.

Comment: Thanks...that's the answer I did not want to read...but it's most certainly the correct one :-)

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly if you could accept it.